# Display the maximum value of a SEQ field

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, field-codes

When inserting tables in a document, I use a header such as :

`Table 1 - Title`

If the table is bigger than one page I use a header on each page, page 2 of 3 for the table will have :

`Table 1 - Title (2/3)`

The number of the current page is generated with a SEQ field :

`Table 1 - Title ({SEQ Table1}/3)`

I'd like to use a field to update the total number of pages used for the table which would be the maximum value generated by `{SEQ Table1}` (the value `3` in my example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of ways you could do it:

Select the last `{ SEQ Table1 }` field, then use *Insert->Links->Bookmark* to insert a bookmark (Let's call it `Table1Pages`)

Then use the following field code to insert the value of *that* `{ SEQ }` field

```
{ SEQ Table1 Table1Pages }
```

Make sure you update all the relevant  fields.

The problem with that is that if you add a page to the end of the table, you have to re-insert the bookmark. Another way that is a bit more obvious would be to use a nested field anywhere *after* the final `{ SEQ Table1 }` field to set a bookmark:

```
{ SET Table1Pages { SEQ Table1 \c } }
```

Then use a REF field to display the value:

```
{ REF Table1Pages }
```

or (preferable, IMO)

```
{ Table1Pages }
```

You may have to update the field codes a couple of times to get that working in the case where the REF field comes before the SET field.

(*all* the {  } have to be the special field code brace pairs you can insert using ctrl-F9 on Windows desktop Word.)

Comment: I'll use solution 2, less clicking, thank you. Also I added a \c in the nested SEQ or it would display (3/4) for the last table instead of (3/3).